# how to send attached attachment ,if any user attach the any file to the opportunity after the opportunity stage 100

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

How to send attached attachment to the user, If any user attach any file to the opportunity after the opportunity stage 100(closed won).

```
    public class email_class{
    Public string ToAddresses {get;set;}
    Public string CCAddresses {get;set;}
    Public string opportunityId {get;set;}
    Public string subject {get;set;}
    public string email_body {get;set;}
    public string emailTo {get;set;}
    public string emailCC {get;set;}

    public email_class(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        opportunityId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }

    Public PageReference send(){

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); // set the to address
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {emailTo}); 
        mail.setCcAddresses(new String[] {emailCC});   //set the cc address
        mail.setSubject(subject);
        mail.setBccSender(false);
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(email_body);
        mail.setWhatId(opportunityId);// Set email file attachments 

        List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();

        for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :opportunityId]){  // Add to attachment file list  
            Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();  
            efa.setFileName(a.Name); 
            efa.setBody(a.Body); 
            fileAttachments.add(efa);
        }
        mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);// Send email
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain bit more and what you are trying to do with the query

Comment: I am trying to execute the functionality from trigger :if any user attach the file from opportunity and opportunity stage is 100,then i want to send that attachment to user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write one trigger on Attachment. Please refer [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181538&language=en_US&type=1) document for writing trigger on attachment.

Then use below trigger, It should work I haven't tested it.

```
   trigger SendAttachment on Attachment (after insert) {


    List<Id> prntid = new List<Id>();
    for(Attachment att : Trigger.new){
        String parent_id = att.ParentId;
        if(parent_id.startsWith('006')){
            prntid.add(att.parentId);
        }
    }

    List<Opportunity> oppList = [Select Id,StageName from Opportunity where Id IN : prntid AND StageName = 'Closed Won'];
    Map<Id,string> mStage = new Map<Id,string>();
    for(Opportunity opp : oppList){
        mStage.put(opp.Id,opp.StageName);
    }

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    String[] toAddresses = new List<String>();
    toAddresses.add('abc@gmail.com');

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
    mail.setSubject('Give the subject......');
    mail.setPlainTextBody('Test');


    List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
    for(Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength,ContentType from Attachment where ParentId IN :prntid ]){
        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
        efa.setFileName(a.Name);
        efa.setBody(a.Body);
        efa.setContentType(a.ContentType);
        fileAttachments.add(efa);
    }
    system.debug('attachement.. '+fileAttachments);
    mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
}
```